# How display success message after submit the form particular product catalog?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create success message after submit the checkout form but i need only particular category product like "made in india" category option in my website.
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phhtml

## __('Your order has been received.') ?>

getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?>

getOrderId()):?>
getCanViewOrder()) :?>

__('Your order # is: %s.', sprintf('%s', $this->escapeHtml($this->getViewOrderUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()))) ?>

__('Your order # is: %s.', $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?>

__('You will receive an order confirmation email with details of your order and a link to track its progress.') ?>

getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()) :?>

__('Click here to print a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
        getChildHtml() ?>

getAgreementRefId()): ?>

__('Your billing agreement # is: %s.', sprintf('%s', $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementRefId())))?>

getRecurringProfiles()):?>

__('Your recurring payment profiles:'); ?>

getCanViewProfiles() ? sprintf('%s', $this->escapeHtml($this->getProfileUrl($profile)), $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id'))) : $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id')));?>

__('Payment profile # %s: "%s".', $profileIdHtml, $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'schedule_description')))?>

quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" onclick="window.location='getUrl() ?>'">__('Continue Shopping') ?>

This is my code but one want to update this code. When customer preaches "made in india" category product then we want after submit checkout form success message will be ("Time check 16:01 PM to next day 15:59 PM. The product will be delivered next day. User can check this by entering the pincode in the text box. For e.g., I ordered one product at 23:31 PM on 21th August 2016, then user should be notified "Purchase now to get the parcel tomorrow. To check your eligibility please enter your pin code in the text box".") But only particular this category other category product some success message as my code already

Please help me....

Comment: Provide some iformation or code example or screenshot with your questions

Comment: The "best" way would be to add a category attribute for whether to show this message. You can then loop products in checkout success and find their categories, check the attribute and display if required.

Comment: yes i update my question Murtuza and Robbie Averill.... Please provide me some solution this issues.